# Modal appends to the bottom instead of showing as overlay(Calendly) when used with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have added calendly to my website and am having issues making it work with a custom button.

I am loading the calendly script into react using

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
  
    script.src = "https://calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js";
    script.async = true;
  
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  
    return () => {
      document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
  }, []);
```

and then added an onclick property to a button

```
onClick={() => {window.Calendly.initPopupWidget({url:calendymain});return false;}}
```

However when I click this button the modal gets added to the bottom of the webpage instead of showing up as an overlay.
[image]

Note : This was working a few hours ago, but since I deployed it to vercel it has stopped working on both local as well as vercel(no changes were made in the period between)

I am using reactJS, tailwindCss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made some dumb mistakes but basically did not import CSS for the caledly widget.

Added this in App.js in the header tag

```
<link href="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

This worked previously as I think it cached the calendly CSS somewhere when I imported it via the library.